# From design to user story mapping

Tags: user-story

We have ran a design sprint after the end of which we managed to test a simplified flow of the designs elaborated with 14 users. We are now bringing those learnings into the design making sure that we address those feedback in the design.

QUESTION: how would you move from the design into planning the dev work? I was thinking of running a similar activity to a story mapping, taking the design as starting point breaking it down by key Tasks with the steps associated to it.

Doe this make sense? Has anybody ran a similar exercise?

Comment: I'd suggest you talk to your engineers and see how they want it broken down and what information would be useful to them.

Answer (score 1):

In short: Talk with your devs.

In long:

The technical details for implementations can range from "very hard" to "very easy" in ways which are very non-obvious to designers.

[image: xkcd: Tasks]

As such, involving your devs in planning very early on can help you decide what to make part of the MVP and perhaps even extend the scope of the MVP in unexpected ways. Devs may also find that certain tasks which you think design-wise should be far apart actually make lots of sense closer together - for example, being able to save email drafts and a sticky note system may be the same thing on a technical level.

So talk to your devs. Ask them what they need broken down, ask them from which direction they'd approach it, if there's any project management methods they prefer and so on.